# Bisection method in matlab

Tags: matlab, bisection

```
function r=bisection(f,a,b,tol,nmax)
% function r=bisection(f,a,b,tol,nmax)
% inputs: f: function handle or string
% a,b: the interval where there is a root
% tol: error tolerance
% nmax: max number of iterations
% output: r: a root
c=(a+b)/2;
nit=1;
if f(a)*f(b)>0
    r=NaN;
    fprintf("The bisection method failed \n")
else
    while(abs(f(c))>=tol && nit<nmax)
        if (f(c)*f(a))<0
            c=(a+c)/2;
        elseif (f(c)*f(b))<0
            c=(a+b)/2;
        elseif f(c)==0
            break;
        end
        nit=nit+1;
    end
    r=c;
end
```

Above are my code for the Bisection method. I am confused about why that code don't work well. The result of `f(c)` is repeated every three times when running this. Does anyone can tell me why this code won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you forgot to consider that you need to reset one of the 2 extremes `a` and `b` of the interval to `c` at each iteration.

```
function r=bisection(f,a,b,tol,nmax)
% function r=bisection(f,a,b,tol,nmax)
% inputs: f: function handle or string
% a,b: the interval where there is a root
% tol: error tolerance
% nmax: max number of iterations
% output: r: a root
c=(a+b)/2;
nit=1;
if f(a)*f(b)>0
    r=NaN;
    fprintf("The bisection method failed \n")
else
    while(abs(f(c))>=tol && nit<nmax)
        if (f(c)*f(a))<0
            b=c;                % new line
            c=(a+c)/2;            
        elseif (f(c)*f(b))<0
            a=c;                % new line
            c=(c+b)/2;
        elseif f(c)==0
            break;
        end
        nit=nit+1;
    end
    r=c;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the boundaries for next round of bisection (within your `while` loop) like below

```
function r = bisection(f,a,b,tol,nmax)
c=mean([a,b]);
nit=1;
if f(a)*f(b)>0
    r=NaN;
    fprintf("The bisection method failed \n")
else
    while(abs(f(c))>=tol && nit<nmax)
        if (f(c)*f(a))<0
            b=c;                      
        elseif (f(c)*f(b))<0
            a=c;
        elseif f(c)==0
            break;
        end
        c=mean([a,b]);
        nit=nit+1;
    end
    r=c;
end
end
```